# RegEx match entire text in between delimiters with a certain string

Tags: regex, preg-match

I've searched everywhere and couldn't find any similar problem.

So I wanted to get the entire string in between delimiters with a specific text inside it.

Example:

I wanted to get the whole string in between `"` that contains the text `hotelscombined.com`

This is the string to be searched from:
`<a id="fake-id" href="http://hotelscombined.com?param=1&param=2&param=3">"Hello I'm a link"</a>`

Result should be `http://hotelscombined.com?param=1&param=2&param=3` and not `Hello world` or `fake-id`

This is not limited to HTML/XML attributes only. It could be done on non-HTML/XML elements

Example:

Content to be searched:
`Hello world I'm not an "html or xml" I could be "just random text"`

Text to be match, anything that has the word `random` and surrounded by quotes `"`

So `"just random text"` is matched.

I tried it here https://regex101.com/r/qI8bS4/1 using this regex `\".*?(hotelscombined\.com).*?\"` However it seems to be greedy and reaches to the next quote `"`.

Comment: @nhahtdh Duplicate? Seriously? Please read the problem first. This is not limited to HTML elements.

Comment: Try [`href="([^"]*?hotelscombined\.com.*?)"`](https://regex101.com/r/qI8bS4/3)

Comment: @Tushar hey thanks! that works I can see you used `[^"]*?` from the way I understand this it matches everything except `"` is that correct? I also added that at the end seems to work fine as well [`"([^"]*?hotelscombined\.com[^"]*?)"`](https://regex101.com/r/qI8bS4/4)

Comment: Yes, you can see the explanation on regex101 in the top right corner.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Tushar for helping.

I've come up with this solution  [`"([^"]*?hotelscombined\.com[^"]*?)"`](https://regex101.com/r/qI8bS4/4)

For generality: Pattern is like this `DELIM([^DELIM]*?TEXT[^DELIM]*?)DELIM`

Where:
`DELIM = The delimiter`
`TEXT = The specific text you want enclosed`.

The key is to use `[^DELIM]*?` to match all characters except your delimiter and make it lazy search.